# Convert Date Format Perl

Tags: string, perl, date

I have dates in YYYYMMDD format and need it in DD-MON-YYYY format. For example, if I input 19001201, then I want 01-DEC-1900 out. Is there a somewhat easy way to do this? I.e. I am currently splitting the string, then using a hash to convert the month... What modules in Perl can easily edit dates?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it not working?

Comment: I have a long set of code that splits the date and then a hash that outputs the value... Just wondered if Perl had a "date-like" class like Java.

Comment: There are many Perl date modules. DateTime is probably the best, but Time::Piece is core.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's a piece of cake to find now! I struggled to find it!!!

Comment: For example: `perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[0], "%Y%m%d")->strftime("%d-%b-%Y")' 19001201`

Comment: Matt Jacob, I'll accept your answer if you post it! I up-voted the other one!

Answer (score 3):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format1 = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y%m%d',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $format2 = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%d-%b-%Y',
   locale   => 'en',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format1->parse_datetime('19001201');
say uc($format2->format_datetime($dt));          # 01-DEC-1900
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally prefer [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) over [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), but Time::Piece has the advantage of being a core module, and in this case, it does everything you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y%m%d')->strftime('%d-%b-%Y');
}

__DATA__
19001201
20170417
20170505
```

Output:

```
01-Dec-1900
17-Apr-2017
05-May-2017
```